# Disable splashscreen - BOOTLOGO disabled

Tags: root-access, boot, bootloader

First off all I must start by saying that I am not an Android Expert.

I Have some android TV box ( not a phone ) which is of some unknown third party chinese vendor . it is already rooted .

I need to personalize it as much as I can, and I have already made the wallpapers, launcher, and bootanimation

The only thing I have left (and the most annoying one ) is the splash screen.

Now, I have read a lot of posts / articles about it , and I even made a rgb656 .img file, but the whole process is very complicated ( and potentially dangerous ).
So now all i want is to totally disable it .

I opened `init.ec` and there I saw :

```
...

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH /vendor/lib:system/lib
export ANDROID_BOOTLOGO 1
export ANDROID_ROOT /system

....
```

So I wonder , does changing the `ANDROID_BOOTLOGO 1` to `ANDROID_BOOTLOGO 0` will disable the splashscreen ?

Is there any other easy way of doing it ?
Any advice ?
(If you can avoid answers like "try and see" - I am afraid to brick it ..

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if boot_logo = splash_screen in Chinese ;) But I'd say give it a try. I cannot see any reason that it should "brick" anything (while changing one of the other two settings certainly have the potential, this one is not very likely to do so).

As a reference, see [this XDA Developers thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=745870) which is dealing with that issue:

> From what I understand, you need to change the `init.rc` file in \
>
> `setprop ro.kernel.android.bootanim 0`
> `setprop debug.sf.nobootanimation 1`
>
> or simply change export `ANDROID_BOOTLOGO 1` to export `ANDROID_BOOTLOGO 0` also in `init.rc`
>
> However, all changes to init.rc are gone after restarting the phone....

Which brings up another information: It's very likely that your `init.rc` resides on a RAM disk, so those changes will have no effect at all. In that case, you would have to modify the boot image (`boot.img`). I never did that, but this carries potential to entirely brick it (as it happened to the guy in the linked XDA thread, by the way).

Comment: Thanks for the info. I have already tried it before your answer, and you are correct. the changes disappear after boot. I am almost sure there is some default location where one could put an image with a default name ( like boot.img, or splash.img or whatever ) but it seems that those locaation change with kernels , And I really do not know where mine is (or whatthe name would be )

Comment: Yes, that's also correct -- and there're even apps on the playstore for this (just [searching for "splash boot"](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=splash+boot&c=apps) will turn up some, amongst some unrelated stuff). Maybe they work on your device?

Comment: Thanks , But those are usually very device specific . I already actually made an image , and I was planning of just put it inside any folder until I will find the right one , but there is one problem and it is that I do not know the boot resolution . And if I will make the wrong size , it can actually brick the device ( or not brick, but prevent boot completion )

Comment: Yepp: better safe than sorry. As I'm not experienced with that, I have to leave it to someone else.